# encounter a crash with generic function in unity5.3/5.4

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want simulate a functional programming Option class with map and flatMap but It can't work in Unity engine. as a example, I create three .cs file as follow:

1 .NET 2.0 default delegate is't **covariance** and **contravariance**, so I override it.

```
using System;   
namespace Functional
{
  public delegate R Func<out R>();
  public delegate R Func<in A, out R>(A a);
  public delegate R Func<in A, in B, out R>(A a, B b);
  public delegate R Func<in A, in B, in C, out R>(A a, B b, C c);
  public delegate R Func<in A, in B, in C, in D, out R>(A a, B b, C c, D d);
  public delegate R Func<in A, in B, in C, in D, in E, out R>(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e);

  public delegate void Action<in A>(A a);
}
```

2 define `Option` classes

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Functional;

namespace Lorance.RxScoket.Util {
  public interface IOption<out T> {
    void Foreach (Action<T> func);
    IOption<R> Map<R> (Func<T, R> func);
    IOption<R> FlatMap<R> (Func<T, IOption<R>> func);
    bool IsEmpty();
    T Get ();
  }

  public static class IOptionEx {
    public static T GetOrElse<T> (this IOption<T> opt, Func<T> defaultValue) {
      return opt.IsEmpty() ? defaultValue() : opt.Get();
    }
  }

  public abstract class Option<T>: IOption<T> {
    public abstract bool IsEmpty ();

    public abstract T Get ();

    public void Foreach (Action<T> act) {
      if (!IsEmpty ()) {
        act (Get());
      }
    }

    public IOption<R> Map<R>(Func<T, R> func) {
      if (IsEmpty ())
        return new None<R> ();
      else
        return new Some<R>(func (Get()));
    }

    public IOption<R> FlatMap<R>(Func<T, IOption<R>> func) {
      if (IsEmpty ())
        return new None<R> ();
      else
        return func (Get());
    }

    public static Option<T> apply(T value){
      if (value == null)
        return new None<T> ();
      else
        return new Some<T> (value);
    }

    public static Option<T> Empty = new None<T>();
  }

  public class Some<T> : Option<T> {
    T value;

    public Some(T value){
    this.value = value;
  }

    public override bool IsEmpty() {return false;}

    public override T Get() {
    return value;
  }
  }

  public class None<T> : Option<T> {
    public override bool IsEmpty() {return true;}
    public override T Get() {
    throw new NoSuchElementException ("None.Get()");
  }
  }

  public class NoSuchElementException : System.SystemException {
    public NoSuchElementException(string message)
      : base(message)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

3 crash example

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Lorance.RxScoket.Util;

public class TestFlatMap : MonoBehaviour {
  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    Dog d = new Dog ();
    IOption<Dog> dogOpt = new Some<Dog> (d);

    //ok
    Dog dog = dogOpt.GetOrElse<Dog> (() => new Dog());

    //crash at this point. does it care about polymorphism? but it works on pure .net project
    Animal animal = dogOpt.GetOrElse<Animal> (() => new Cat());

    print ("r2 -" + animal);
  }
}

public class Animal {}
public class Dog: Animal {}
public class Cat: Animal {}
```

Does someone also meets the problem and how to solve it?
a complete crash example at : https://github.com/Unlimited-Works/crash-eg

Get the crash with this step:
1. Open the project with unity editor.
2. Open scene 'eg.unity'.
3. Press play.
4. result: Unity crashes.

it crashes when executing 'TestFlapMap.cs':
Animal animal = dogOpt.GetOrElse (() => new Cat());

if you also encounter the promblem please give me a vote at [unity issues](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/editor-crashes-in-mono-magic-trampoline-when-calling-a-generic-function), it has delay one month ago and not any response from Unity official.

thanks

Comment: I've been poking at the project, I can't figure out a work around. If I had to supect somthing it would be that the version of Mono they are running is unhappy with covariance. (if you where curious I narrowed it down to the fact it is crashing on the `opt.IsEmpty()` call inside `GetOrElse`, it never gets inside the `IsEmpty` call. Not putting it all on one line helps point out where the error is.)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, it will crash at .Net2.0 under Unity Editor.I also test .Net4.0, its works.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, with the `Dog dog = ...` and `Animal animal = ...` in `testFlatMap ` class. I think it seems a error of generic function.

Comment: testFlatMap should be TestFlatMap.   Note that it is a ***component in an ECS system***.  To begin with, what object is your instance of TestFlatMap attached to?  What other components are attached to it?

Comment: @JoeBlow, only this one script component attached.em.. sorry for the name.

Comment: @JoeBlow if you load up the `eg.unity` scene it is just the default "new scene" with a empty GameObject named `eg` added with the TestFlatMap script attached to it.